# Is this a valid structure of an app

Tags: iphone

I have the following structure in my app, is this a correct/valid way of doing it?

UINavigationController attached to the window, the rootcontroller in this navigationcontroller is a UIViewController that presents a tableview. When a user taps one of the rows a UITabBarController is pushed on the stack.

This works, however I began to be unsure when I read this:

> Because the UITabBarController class
>   inherits from the UIViewController
>   class, tab bar controllers have their
>   own view that is accessible through
>   the view property. When deploying a
>   tab bar interface, you must install
>   this view as the root of your window.
>   Unlike other view controllers, a tab
>   bar interface should never be
>   installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended, but it should be OK. The aweful Wordpress app also does this. This depends on the design of your app.

I'm not shure about Apple's approval.

Comment: What would be the correct way of presenting a UITabBar only when a user taps one of the rows then?

Comment: Not at all. A tab bar should be shown either constantly or never. Also read the iOS HIG, where this is mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand why this is "not" recommended, but do you think it will be approved when submitting?

Comment: @Andreas: It probably will, since WordPress for iOS was approved and is on the App Store.

Comment: @BoltClock unfortunately it did :(

Comment: @Time Machine: Man I wish I were on the dev team, but I'm just a beta tester. I can't do much about that codebase (which, looking at it, I agree is a mess).

Comment: @Andreas: A toolbar and a tab bar serve different purposes. I guess it really depends on your application structure (what the tabs are for). It wouldn't *hurt* to use a tab bar controller if you really had to...

Comment: Or, could I use UITabBar and just add it as a subview without the controller? Would that be OK?

Comment: @BoltClock lets fork it under a different name and make it better :)

Comment: @Andreas this really depends on your app. You might try both things in the simulator and see what's the best way.

Comment: Okey, but is it correct that a UITabBar(with a UIViewController implementing the UITabBarDelegate) can be added as a subview without breaking this "rule"?

Comment: @Andreas it is possible, but Apple begs you not to do it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html 'A tab bar appears at the bottom edge of the screen and should be accessible from every location in the application.'

Comment: @Andreas maybe you should consider a UISegmentedControl in the UINavigationBar of your UINavigationController.

Comment: @Andreas what tabs do you want to use?

Comment: What do you mean, I really want to use the TabBar tabs because it looks best that way, if that is your question?

Comment: @Andreas what are the tabs you want the user to choose from? How many tabs are there?

Comment: Ah, I have "Home/main" view when the use opens the application. On this screen it is 4 rows. When a user taps one of the rows a UITabBarController is pushed on stack displaying 3-4 tabs in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is not recommended (and thus *might* not get approved - now or at a later point!) is user confusion.

Users are used to regard the tab bar as top-level navigation. So if dig down using the table and navigation, and then getting a UITabBar, this is horrible for navigation as the user doesn't know what to expect.

The solution here, of course depending on the use case, is a "switch" in the navigation bar or a toolbar. UISegmentedControl would be a natural choice.